# Updating nested array inside array using reactivemongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I'm trying to update an element in nested lists with scala and reactive mongo. I tried this:

```
  def updatethirdList(secondListElementId: UUID, firstObject: FirstObject): Future[Either[String, UUID]] = {
    val query = Json.obj("secondList.thirdList._id" -> secondListElementId)
    val update = Json.obj("$set" -> Json.obj("secondList.$.thirdList" -> sessionType))
    collection.update(query, update).map {
      case result if result.ok == true => Right(secondListElementId)
      case result => Left(result.message)
    }
  }
```

the structure:

```
{
"firstList":[{
            "secondList":[{
                         "thirdList":[{
                                     "firstObject":""
                                     }]
                         }]
            }]
}
```

the problem with my code is that it's gave this result:
firstList.0.secondList.0.thirdList = firstObject
it should give for example this : 
firstList.0.secondList.0.thirdList.0 = firstObject

I tried this:

```
val update = Json.obj("$set" -> Json.obj("secondList.$.thirdList.$" -> firstObject))
```

but I get this error: MongoDB: Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path

Any help please

Comment: Have you tried in MongoShell to design the query first?

Comment: No but when I tried this: val update = Json.obj("$set" -> Json.obj("secondList.0.thirdList.0" -> firstObject)) its update the first element in the thirdList

Comment: First try to have a working query, before encoding it in your app

Comment: @Rajeun, Did you find the solution?